# PHP - Return Multidimensional Array Through Foreach

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I'm trying to return a value from a multidimensional array, but it doesn't seem to be working.

**Array** -

```
[players] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [player] => Necro
                [score] => 0
                [deaths] => 0
                [gq_name] => 
                [gq_kills] => 
                [gq_deaths] => 0
                [gq_score] => 0
                [gq_ping] => 
            )

    )
```

**PHP Foreach**

```
<?php  
$dayzplayers = $results["dayz"]["players"];
          foreach($dayzplayers as $k => $v) {
                  echo ' <b>'.$v["player"].'</b>';
              } ?>
```

Comment: I cannot spot any "dayz" in your array... So `$dayzplayers` is empty, the loop won't loop.

Comment: I specify multiple games in the array, thats how I'm specifying the server query specifically.

Comment: If you do a print_r($v); inside the foreach, what do you get?

Comment: And you don't think you should post that structure here when you want to get help? How are we meant to help when you don't show your real code?

Comment: @m4t1t0 It returns Array ( [player] => Necro [score] => 190 [deaths] => 0 [gq_name] => [gq_kills] => [gq_deaths] => 0 [gq_score] => 190 [gq_ping] => )

Comment: @arkascha If you'd like my post to be 250 lines long, then sure! I was just trying to not be obnoxious. It returns a LOT of information.

Comment: If it's too long then use a pastebin. But asking a question and leaving out the data makes little sense, sorry.

Comment: @arkascha I didn't feel that outsourcing to Pastebin in the question was resourceful. Sorry. I can do that for you if you'd like.

Comment: Not for me. For you _if_ you want help.

Comment: Apart from that: what do you mean by "it doesn't seem to be working" ? What _do_ you get? _Exactly_?

Comment: I believe $v is a string and not an array based on your code. Change `echo ' <b>'.$v["player"].'</b>';` to `echo ' <b>'.$v.'</b>';`

Comment: @Jason: no, he posted the debug output above. It is an array, he just didn't post his real data structure.

Comment: @Jason Nope, its an array =/ Because the echo reads off "Array" :P

Comment: there seems to a special character `[SOHplayer] => Necro`; analyse it.

Comment: I'm getting bored with waiting for the rest of code.

Comment: Ok, this does not lead anywhere: 1.) _all_ relevant code and data 2.) what is it you actually get in detail? 3.) any entries in the servers log error file ?

Comment: I can agree with @SparKot's guess, but i have another one too. You `echo` output in a wrong place, check source code if output is there.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/avHn3m38 -_-

Comment: If `print_r($v);` prints the output you supplied, then `echo $v['player'];` should successfully output "Necro".

Comment: Outputting "Score" works. But not "player"...I have not a clue what the issue is, I just searched and I'm not using ["player"] in any other array other then the other game server queries.

Answer (score 1):

The ['player'] index appears to have an invisible control character in the key SOH (Start of Heading)

Try `echo ' <b>'.$v[chr(1) . "player"].'</b>';` instead of `echo ' <b>'.$v["player"].'</b>';`

Comment: @Necro. I have amended my answer with a reccomendation

Answer (score 0):

If the data is what you posted in the first listing, this should work:

```
foreach($dayzplayers as $player) {
    echo $player[chr(1).'player'];
}
```

as per http://codepad.org/kUYueGVh

Comment: Its so weird. Because when I do a var_dump on $player, it shows the array and clearly shows "player", yet when I do the above code. No output =/ check http://esclan.org/esclan/dayz# to see.

Comment: @Necro Open the dump in an editor where you can see non-graphic characters.

Comment: What happens if you `echo $player['score'];`

Comment: It returns the score. But yet when I try 'player' nothing. The array comes back null.

Comment: `echo (string) $player['player'];` or if it indeed does have a SOH character `echo var_export($player['player']);` See if that helps

Comment: @Tuim It comes back null when I do the var_export method. How would I correct this SOH character? I tried doing ob_flush.

Comment: `echo preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF]/', '', $player['player'])` Try that

Comment: According to this http://codepad.org/ac2CQYnh it should work fine even if there is a SOH in the string..

Comment: Oh I just now noticed that it is in the key of the array try this: `echo $player[chr(1).'player'];`